# Problems using the HTML::Template module

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm unable to execute the HTML::Template function in the CGI.

I'm following a simple tutorial that I found here: http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template

I created a new file on my server in the home path as [test.tmpl](http://csvlife.com/test.tmpl).

I created a new file named frt.cgi ... (is that the issue here? should it be a different file extention??)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use HTML::Template;

# open the html template
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => '/test.html');

# fill in some parameters
$template->param(HOME => $ENV{HOME});
$template->param(PATH => $ENV{PATH});

# send the obligatory Content-Type and print the template output
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", $template->output;
```

I've modified the 1st line to reflect my host provided program path for perl. I don't know what the -w does I just know I've tried this with and without it. Also I've tried changing the code a bit like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use HTML::Template;
```

I've searched...
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HTML%3A%3ATEMPLATE+&submit=search
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HTML%3A%3ATEMPLATE
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HTML%3A%3ATEMPLATE+PERL&submit=search

Yet I still do not see the answer. 
I even searched google for .TMPL Encoding because I thought there may be some special type needed. Please help.

Comment: .tmpl files are just text files. -w just turns on warnings. It's equivalent to `use warnings;` It would help if you posted an error message. Are you sure HTML::Template is installed? It's not a standard module.

Comment: @Cfreak [Not quite equivalent](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your server logs, you'll probably see an error message along the lines of:

```
HTML::Template->new() : Cannot open included file /test.html : file not found.
```

You need to provide the path *on the file system*, not a URI relative to the generated document.

Comment: Not only that but I just noticed he's referencing test.html but his template name is test.tmpl

Comment: Sorry I've changed this code around so much that it does still say test.html on the cgi I will change and update. Also I've just checked my installed mods and I do see the HTML Module on there.

Comment: K so I modified the incorrect line to this:my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'httpcolon//csvlife.com/test.tmpl');

Comment: @DieVers — Filename on the file system, not an HTTP URI.

Comment: This is what I show in the path when I edit it:                                        /home/modfresh/public_html/test.tmpl so do I put this whole thing in the '' or do I just put/test.tmpl also thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, you likely specified the wrong path - change /test.html to test.html.
Also, it is possible that there is no $ENV{HOME} variable in your system so set up flag  die_on_bad_params to 0:

```
my $template = HTML::Template->new(
filename => 'test.html',
die_on_bad_params => 0,
);
```

Also, don't forget to mark your Perl file as executable by chmod 755.

Option -w makes Perl to enable warnings, so there is no point to write `use warnings;` afterwards.
You can check what Perl command line options do by using module B::Deparse, like this ($^W variable disables/enables warnings):

```
perl -w -MO=Deparse -e "print;"
```

This would print:

```
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
print $_;
```

Comment: `chmod 777`??? Yeeks! don't give advise when you obviously don't know what you're doing. (and no, don't use `-w`, `use warnings`.)